# Exiting two concurrent queues with three threads in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, concurrency, queue

I'm having problems with quitting my multithreaded, multi-queued c++ program. The diagram shows the queue and thread structure. The diagram is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGhXs.png

In short, I have three threads, and two concurrent queues. The second_handler(second_thread) pops from the first queue and pushes to the second queue. All (seems to) works fine, until I want to quit the program by hitting a keyboard key. I get this error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
  what():  boost::lock_error
Aborted

Here is my code:
*main*

```
int main() {
        startMultiThreading();
        cout <<"I"<<endl;
    }
```

*startMultiThreading*

```
void startMultiThreading() {
    boost::thread_group someVar_workers;
    boost::thread_group someOtherVar_workers;

    concurrent_queue<someVar* > someVar_queue(&someVar_workers);
    concurrent_queue<someOtherVar*> someOtherVar_queue(&someOtherVar_workers);

    boost::thread *first_thread = new boost::thread(first_handler, &someVar_queue);
    boost::thread *second_thread = new boost::thread(second_handler, &someVar_queue, &someOtherVar_queue);
    boost::thread *third_thread = new boost::thread(third_handler, &someOtherVar_queue);

    someVar_workers.add_thread(first_thread);
    someVar_workers.add_thread(second_thread);

    someOtherVar_workers.add_thread(second_thread);
    someOtherVar_workers.add_thread(third_thread);

    while (true) {
        if (thread_should_exit) {
            cout << "threads should be killed" << endl;
            while (!someVar_queue.empty()) {
                usleep(1000);
            }
            someVar_workers.remove_thread(second_thread);
            while (!someOtherVar_queue.empty()) {
                usleep(1000);
            }
            someOtherVar_queue.cancel();
            someVar_workers.join_all();
            someOtherVar_workers.remove_thread(second_thread);
            someOtherVar_workers.join_all();
            break;
        }
        usleep(10000);
    }
    cout << "H" << endl;
}
```

What I would like is the program to finish both queues and then terminates normally. What I would expect is to see "I" printed before the program to terminate. Here is the output:

```
    End of first_handler
    threads should be 
    second_handler is canceled
    End of second_handler
    H
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'concurrent_queue<someOtherVar*>::Canceled'
Aborted
    Press [Enter] to close the terminal ...
```

What am I doing wrong when closing the threads and the queues?

Thank you

Comment: This is a huge amount of code, please reduce it to something smaller. Also: what is wrong about an abort exception being thrown when you hit the abort command?

Answer (score 2):

First, see comment from KillianDS - your example is too long.

The other thing is: **Do never call a destructor directly!!**

The destructor is something special and the language garantuees to call it at the end of scope of the variable. If you call it manually, it will get called a second time which most probably leeds to undefined behaviour.

[Calling destructor manually](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.5)

Comment: Thanks KillianDS and G. Martinek for the replies. Two wise lessons learned about destructors and exceptions. I did not succeed in getting the cout in the main printed. But it might not be necessary.